# Log out from facebook using the facebook c# sdk on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk, logout

When I try to log out(both using my own button and the one provided in the SDK) I am "able" to log out. The reason I use the quotation marks is that when I will try to log in again, it is automatically logging me in as the previous logged in user. Thus, I am not able to change user. I'm assuming that this is some cache issues in the web browser or something like that. Anyone know if this will be fixed when the sdk is out of its alpha? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the FB authentication cookies are still in the WebBrowser data.

Here is the code that clears the WebBrowser cookies (no matter which instance of WebBrowser it's called on):

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually thought of that but didn't try it, because I couldn't get the correct instance. If you say it doesn't matter, I'll try it! Thanks!